# Can I pass an object using xmlrpc in java

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I want to pass an object using xmlrpc as this is the only possible way it seems that I can pass an Integer and a String to a method on the server. Is it possible to do this using an object? If not is there some other way of doing it?

I have attempted to do it but am getting this error:

> JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #java.io.IOException: unsupported
>   Java type: class Client.Article

This is the code on the client side:

```
public void addHash()
{
    try {
            addAuthorName = txtAddAuthorName.getText();
            int addArticleNumber = Integer.parseInt(txtAddArticleNumber.getText()); 
            newArticle = new Article(addAuthorName, addArticleNumber);

        Vector<Object> addArticleArglist = new Vector<Object>();
        addArticleArglist.addElement(newArticle);
        System.out.println(newArticle);

        // make the call
        String callit = ("GetSize.addHash");
        articleID = (Integer) client.execute(callit, addArticleArglist);
    } // Use XmlRpcException errors
    catch (XmlRpcException exception) {
        System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #"
                + Integer.toString(exception.code) + ": "
                + exception.getCause() + "" + exception.toString());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" + exception.toString());
    }
```

}

This is the code on the server side however by using System.out.println I have discovered that for whatever reason none of the code within this method is being executed:

```
public void addHash(Article newArticle)
   {
       theHashtable.addHash(newArticle.getArticleName(), newArticle.getAuthorID());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `ws-xmlrpc` the documentation states the following:

```
DOM nodes, or JAXB objects, can be transmitted. So are objects implementing the java.io.Serializable interface.
```

So by declaring your object serializable you would be able to transmit it. Depending what you want to do it might be a good idea to take a good look at jaxb.

See http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/ for more info.

Comment: it's just a simulation for my degree and we're learning xmlrpc :) I'm guessing it's ws-xmlrpc :) it is produced by apache I think :)